# What dimension can the intersection of spaces with Schauder basis take?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{h_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in H$ be a Schauder basis in $H$

Let
$$
V=
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty
\overline{
\operatorname{
span
}}
\{h_m\}_{m \geq n}
$$

Is it possible that
$$
\dim V=1
$$

In general, what values can dimension take?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V$ is always equal to $\{0\}$.

Let $v\in V$. Then
$$
v \in \overline{span}\{ h_m : \ m \ge n\} 
$$
for all $n$. Since $(h_n)$ is a Schauder basis, we have
$$
v = \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m h_m = (\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} a_m h_m) + (\sum_{m=n}^{\infty} a_m h_m).
$$
Assume $v\ne0$. Let $n$ be the smallest index such that $a_n \ne0$.
Then
$$
v = a_n h_n + (\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} a_m h_m).
$$
The vector $v$ as well as the vector $\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} a_m h_m$
belongs to $\overline{span}\{ h_m : \ m \ge n+1\} $.
Hence
$$
h_n \in \overline{span}\{ h_m : \ m \ge n+1\}.
$$
But this is impossible: Let $f_n$ be the $n$-th coordinate functional, which maps $v$ to $a_n$, i.e., $f(v) = a_n$. Then $f$ is continuous. And $f_n(h_n)=1$ and $f_n(h_m)=0$ for all $m\ge n+1$.